# iOS UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification Without Memory Leak?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

I currently make use of this method in my objective-C app:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleEnteredForeground) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
```

If I don't remove it with

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
```

am I at risk of a memory leak? Or is there a good way to utilize this notification without the risk of a memory leak?

Comment: `NSNotificationCenter` doesn't retain its observers, so no, you aren't at risk of a memory leak.

Comment: word! Feel free to toss in an answer and I'll accept it!

Comment: @TomHammond But there is more to it than that. There is a danger of a dangling pointer (prior to iOS 9).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no danger of a memory leak; the notification center's reference to your observer `self` is weak.

But there *is* a danger — namely, that `self` will go out of existence and that the notification center will later attempt to send it a notification. This will cause a horrific crash, one that is very difficult to track down (dangling pointer).

That is why you must be certain to unregister your observer in iOS 8 and before.

Starting in iOS 9, however, this ceases to be a problem, because the notification center's reference to your observer is not *simply* weak but is ARC-weak. This means that the reference to a released observer becomes `nil`. The notification center detects this and stops sending notifications to it, safely.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-FoundationOlderNotes/index.html#X10_11Notes "In OS X 10.11 and iOS 9.0 NSNotificationCenter and NSDistributedNotificationCenter will no longer send notifications to registered observers that may be deallocated..."